# cURL with proxy does not work

Tags: php, curl, proxy

I want to scrape URLs using cURL with proxies.

When I don't use proxy, URLs gets scraped, but when I do, I get blank page returned.

Here is my code,

```
    global $curl_init;
    $proxy = '201.172.53.123:10000';
//$proxyauth = 'user:password';
    curl_setopt($curl_init, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl_init, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $proxyauth);
    curl_setopt($curl_init, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl_init, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl_init, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

    curl_setopt($curl_init, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.52 Safari/537.17');
    curl_setopt($curl_init, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
   echo  $curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($curl_init);
```

I am using free proxies from http://proxylist.hidemyass.com/

Do I have any mistake in my code? or free proxies dont work at all?

Comment: Try to write `echo curl_error($curl_init);` after `curl_exec` line. What is the output?

Answer (score -1):

First, load proxies into array

```
$proxies_list = array(); 
$proxies_list [] = 'user:password@198.235.11.134:76891';  // Some proxies requires user, password, IP and port no.
$proxies_list [] = 'user:password@198.235.120.69:76891';
$proxies_list [] = 'user:password@198.235.46.176:76891';
$proxies_list [] = '198.235.92.107';  // Some proxies only require IP
$proxies_list [] = '198.235.93.94';
$proxies_list [] = '198.235.94.90:76891'; //Some proxies require IP,port no.
$proxies_list [] = '69.147.240.61:76891';
```

•  Next ,select any random proxy from list to use it later.

```
if (isset($proxies)) {  
    $proxy = $proxies[array_rand($proxies)];   
}
```

Now, after initialising cURL handle, set the CURLOPT_PROXY option of cURL to randomly selected proxy, set all other cURL options, then execute the request and close the handle.

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
// Setting proxy option for cURL
if (isset($proxy)) {    // If the $proxy variable is set, then
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);    // Set CURLOPT_PROXY with proxy in $proxy variable
}

// Set any other cURL options that are required
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$results = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
```